# Application.WorksheetFunction.Match not working as I expected

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am working with an EXCEL file with 11 worksheets, in this configuration:

**VOL_CODE** = The code that I look for. If present in a worksheet, the entire line containing VOL_CODE should be deleted.

Worksheets:

1. “**NEW VOL DATA**” –This is the worksheet that “stays on” (‘Active’ or ‘Selected’) during the whole process.
   Also, here are in range K1:K10 the indications (“X”) if the destination worksheets are selected or not.
2. “**DESTINATION**1”, “**DESTINATION2**”, “**DESTINATION3**” ...  “**DESTINATION10**”
   “Target” worksheets where if VOL_CODE appears AND worksheet is indicated as ‘selected’ (in “NEW VOL DATA” worksheet), it’s line should be removed.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'--- Remove VOL_CODE line from all worksheets -----
   Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim VOL_CODE As String
   Dim PLA, LIN As Integer
   Set ws1 = Worksheets("NEW VOL DATA")   '--- This is the Working Worksheet -----
   VOL_CODE = “RS_123456” ‘--- This is the code to search for -----

   For PLA = 1 To 10
         If UCase(Range("K" & PLA)) <> "X" Then GoTo JUMP_PLA:
         Set ws2 = Worksheets("DESTINATION" & Trim(Str(PLA)))
         Do While True
            On Error GoTo JUMP_PLA:
            LIN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(VOL_CODE, ws2.Range("B:B"), 0)
            ws2.Cells(LIN, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Loop
JUMP_PLA:
   Next PLA

End Sub
```

The problem is, when I execute the code, it goes fine in **DESTINATION1** worksheet, containing or not VOL_CODE (if it does, it loops deleting VOL_CODE’s lines until there are no more), then, when finding no more entries for VOL_CODE, it goes to “JUMP_PLA:” and “Next PLA”... There it starts over, now going to next “**DESTINATIONx**” worksheet (the next selected)... And there’s an error (finding or not a valid entry) when the Application.WorksheetFunction.Match command executes :

Error in execution: 1004
Application definition or Object definition error

I know it must be a stupid error, but as I am a newbie, I cannot visualize it. And it is driving me crazy...
Can anyone give me a light? It would be very appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with F8? Then you don't have to visualize, but can see exactly what is happening at each line of code and take action to correct what goes wrong. Also, with loops deleting rows, it's always better to start from the bottom instead of the top, because a deleted row will mess up the loop's reference to the next row.

Comment: You have a line `do while true`. While WHAT is true? and when does it change to false??

Comment: `VOL_CODE = “RS_123456”` if your actual code has these "smart quotes" then they need to be changed to regular double-quotes.  `If UCase(Range("K" & PLA)) <> "X" Then GoTo JUMP_PLA:`  - here you need to be explicit about which sheet you mean to check the value on.   Maybe `If UCase(ws1.Range("K" & PLA)) <> "X" Then GoTo JUMP_PLA:` ?

Answer (score 2):

### Application.WorksheetFunction.Match to Delete Rows

- The procedure `doDest` is best copied into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) and then called in your button code:

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    doDest
End Sub
```

- I left your code inside it, so you could see the mistakes and some options.
- The rest of the code is just some toys a created to play with, since I've never seen `Match` used for deleting rows.
- IF you wanna play, copy the complete code into a standard module in a **new** workbook and rename a worksheet to `NEW VOL DATA`. In range `K1:K10` of it, enter an `x` in a few cells and you're good to go.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub doDest()
'--- Remove VOL_CODE line from all worksheets -----
   
   ' Speed up the code (you won't see what the macro is doing).
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet 'Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim VOL_CODE As String
   Dim PLA As Long, LIN As Long ' Dim PLA, LIN As Integer
   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook with this code.
   Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("NEW VOL DATA") 'Set ws1 = Worksheets("NEW VOL DATA")   '--- This is the Working Worksheet -----
   VOL_CODE = "RS_123456" '--- This is the code to search for -----

   For PLA = 1 To 10
       'If StrComp(ws1.Range("K" & PLA).Value, "X", vbTextCompare) <> 0 _
         Then GoTo JUMP_PLA
       If UCase(ws1.Range("K" & PLA).Value) <> "X" Then GoTo JUMP_PLA ' If UCase(Range("K" & PLA)) <> "X" Then GoTo JUMP_PLA:
       Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("DESTINATION" & PLA) ' Set ws2 = Worksheets("DESTINATION" & Trim(Str(PLA)))
       Do ' Do While True
           ' On Error GoTo JUMP_PLA:
           ' LIN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(VOL_CODE, ws2.Range("B:B"), 0)
           ' ws2.Cells(LIN, 1).EntireRow.Delete
           On Error Resume Next ' Turn ON error trapping.
           ' "ws2.Columns("B")" is just an option, you can stick with
           ' "ws2.Range("B:B")".
           LIN = Application.WorksheetFunction _
                            .Match(VOL_CODE, ws2.Columns("B"), 0)
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then
               On Error GoTo 0  ' Turn OFF error trapping.
               'Debug.Print "Done with worksheet '" & ws2.Name & "'."
               Exit Do ' or: GoTo JUMP_PLA
           Else
               On Error GoTo 0  ' Turn OFF error trapping.
               ws2.Cells(LIN, 1).EntireRow.Delete
           End If
       Loop
JUMP_PLA:
   Next PLA

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   MsgBox "Deleted rows containing '" & VOL_CODE & "'.", _
          vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

' Deletes all sheets named "DESTINATIONx", where x is from 1 to 10.
Sub deleteDest()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' To prevent Excel from 'complaining'.
        On Error Resume Next              ' If a sheet does not exist.
        wb.Sheets("DESTINATION" & i).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next i
End Sub

' Adds worksheets named "DESTINATIONx", where x is from 1 to 10.
' In each of those worksheets, adds "RS_123456" to up to 100 cells
' in 'random' rows from 1 to 1000 in column 'B'.
Sub createDest()
    
   ' Speed up the code (you won't see what the macro is doing).
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, CurrName As String
    For i = 1 To 10
        CurrName = "DESTINATION" & i
        On Error Resume Next  ' Turn ON error trapping.
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(CurrName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Sheet with current name does not exist.
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets _
                       .Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            ws.Name = CurrName
        'Else ' Sheet with current name exists.
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0       ' Turn OFF error trapping.
        ws.Columns("B").Clear ' Ensures new data if sheets already exist.
        For j = 1 To 100
            ws.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000), "B") _
              .Value = "RS_123456"
        Next j
    Next i
    wb.Sheets(1).Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Counts the number of cells in column 'B' containing a value.
Sub countDest()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print "DESTINATION" & i, wb.Worksheets("DESTINATION" & i) _
                                         .Columns("B") _
                                         .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) _
                                         .Cells.Count
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "DESTINATION" & i, "No cells found."
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

' Ultimate test
Sub testDest()
    deleteDest ' Deletes the sheets.
    createDest ' Creates the worksheets with random data.
    countDest  ' Counts the cells containing "RS_123456" (Debug.Print).
    doDest     ' Deletes the rows containing "RS_123456" in column 'B'.
    countDest  ' Counts the cells containing "RS_123456" (Debug.Print).
    MsgBox "Ultimate: deleted, created, counted, done and counted again."
End Sub

' Initialize
Sub initCreateAndCount()
    deleteDest ' Deletes the sheets.
    createDest ' Creates the worksheets with random data.
    countDest  ' Counts the cells containing "RS_123456" (Debug.Print).
    MsgBox "Initialized: Sheets deleted and created, and cells counted."
End Sub

' Shows how even when the 'dest' sheets exist, new values are generated.
Sub testCreateCount()
    createDest ' Creates the worksheets with random data.
    countDest  ' Counts the cells containing "RS_123456" (Debug.Print).
    MsgBox "Sheets created and cells counted."
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks a lot for the corrections, suggestions and new ideas. Will copy those examples for future reference. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly re-worked version.

See comments for notes about changes

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet '<< need type for every variable,
                                           '   not just the last one...
    Dim VOL_CODE As String
    Dim PLA As Long, LIN As Long, m '<< use Long, not Integer
   
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("NEW VOL DATA")   'Working Worksheet
   
    VOL_CODE = "RS_123456"  '<<< no smart quotes...

    For PLA = 1 To 10
    
        If UCase(ws1.Range("K" & PLA)) = "X" Then
            Set ws2 = Worksheets("DESTINATION" & PLA)
            m = Application.Match(VOL_CODE, ws2.Range("B:B"), 0)
            Do While Not IsError(m) '<<< Test return value instead of
                                    '    trapping run-time error
               ws2.Rows(m).Delete
               m = Application.Match(VOL_CODE, ws2.Range("B:B"), 0)
            Loop
        End If

    Next PLA

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, ideas and tips. The solution from Tim Williams worked A-OK. In fact I was doing a "Do while true", without specifying what to be true. I suspected that whenever the Match command could not find any matches, it would be "not true". Duh! Testing the return value as Tim said, made the button work fine. Thank you!!! (and the smart quotes came from copying the code to a MSWord file, for clipping anly what was necessary).